# Angular2 wrapping component template with div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent component that keeps track of a bunch of child components, i am trying to have each child components template wrapped with a diverse so that I can use *ngIf. There can be any number of children of the parent component.

Not really sure how to explain it better, but this is essentially what I have in a view:

```
<parent>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
</parent>

<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Where ng-content is the child components template. This works, but I need to be able to do some logic to hide child1 template when child2 is selected, for instance. I was thinking to wrap each child component template with an *ngIf, but I can't figure a way to do such a thing

Comment: did't understand your problem yet, but yes you can use `template` tag for using `*ngIf`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that will help you.

```
    import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, AfterContentInit } from 'angular2/core';
    import { TabComponent } from './tab.component';

    @Component({
       selector: 'tabs',
       template:`
        <ul class="tab-container">
          <li class="tab" *ngFor="#tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
            <span>{{tab.tabTitle}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>

      `
    })
    export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {

       @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;

       ngAfterContentInit() {
          let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.active);

          if (activeTabs.length === 0) {
             this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
          }
       }

       selectTab(selectedTab: TabComponent) {
          this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);

          selectedTab.active = true;
       }

    }

import { Component, Input } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'tab',
   template: `
    <div [hidden]="!active" class="pane">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TabComponent {
   @Input() tabTitle: string;
   @Input() active = false;
}
```